# ¿Cómo agregar una interrupción inmediata en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, bucles

estoy tratando de hacer un código mediante una GUI en Raspberry donde el usuario digite por ejemplo 100 ciclos, y un led encienda y apague N veces durante un determinado tiempo, mi problema es que al momento de presionar el botón de apagar led, no lo hace instantáneamente si no hasta que cambia de estado de ON a OFF, por ejemplo, un ciclo consta de un Encendido y Apagado de 30 segundos, es decir 30 segundos encendido y 30 apagado, la cuestión es que si yo enciendo el led y lo quiero apagar a la mitad de los segundos del encendido (15 seg), este no responde hasta cambiar de estado, de ON a OFF. ¿Qué podría agregarle, o que me sugieren hacer para que mi led se apague al instante de presionar mi botón de "APAGAR LED"? Adjunto mi código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Feb 14 20:28:35 2023

@author: braya
"""

import time
from tkinter import *
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("GUI")

miFrame = Frame(raiz, width=300, height=150)
miFrame.pack()

Label(miFrame, text="ON/OFF LED", fg="red", font=("Comic Sans MS",14)).pack()

nombreTexto = Label(miFrame, text="Introduce los ciclos: ")
nombreTexto.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroTexto=Entry(miFrame)
cuadroTexto.pack()
cuadroTexto.config(fg="red", justify="right")

LED = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)

def encenderL():
 num_ciclos = int(cuadroTexto.get())
 for i in range(num_ciclos):
    # Comprobamos si el flag de detener ha sido activado
    if detener_flag:
        break
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(10)
    GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(10)
    GPIO.cleanup() 

def detenerL():
     global detener_flag
     detener_flag = True

detener_flag = False

def encenderL2():
    threading.Thread(target=encenderL).start()

def detenerL2():
    threading.Thread(target=detenerL).start()

botonEnvio= Button(raiz, text="Encender led", command=encenderL2)
botonEnvio.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

botonDetener = Button(raiz, text="Detener led", command=detenerL2)
botonDetener.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

raiz.geometry("700x500")
raiz.config(bg="green")
raiz.config(bd=35)
raiz.config(relief="groove")
raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código, estás utilizando la función `time.sleep()` para hacer pausas de tiempo. La función `time.sleep()` detiene la ejecución del programa por el número de segundos que le pasas como parámetro, lo cual puede causar que el programa no responda inmediatamente cuando se presiona el botón "Detener led".

En lugar de usar `time.sleep()`, podrías utilizar la función `threading.Event()` para crear un objeto que pueda ser utilizado para detener el bucle de encendido y apagado del LED de forma inmediata.

De esta forma se puede hacer uso de `threading.Event()`:

```
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Creamos un objeto Event
detener_event = threading.Event()

def encenderL():
    num_ciclos = int(cuadroTexto.get())
    for i in range(num_ciclos):
        # Comprobamos si el evento de detener ha sido activado
        if detener_event.is_set():
            break
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
        
        # Esperamos a que se active el evento de detener o
        # a que hayan pasado 10 segundos, lo que ocurra primero
        detener_event.wait(timeout=10)
        GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.LOW)
        
        # Esperamos a que se active el evento de detener o
        # a que hayan pasado 10 segundos, lo que ocurra primero
        detener_event.wait(timeout=10)
        GPIO.cleanup()

def detenerL():
    # Establecemos el evento de detener
    detener_event.set()

def encenderL2():
    # Reiniciamos el evento de detener
    detener_event.clear()
    threading.Thread(target=encenderL).start()

def detenerL2():
    threading.Thread(target=detenerL).start()
```

Retroalimentando, se creó un objeto `detener_event` utilizando la función `threading.Event()`. En la función `encenderL()`, comprobamos si el evento ha sido activado utilizando el método `is_set()` del objeto `detener_event`. En lugar de usar `time.sleep()`, utilizamos el método `wait()` del objeto `detener_event` para esperar hasta que se active el evento de detener o hasta que hayan pasado 10 segundos, lo que ocurra primero. De esta manera, el programa responde inmediatamente cuando se presiona el botón de "Detener led". Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Ulises, he hecho la implementación del código que me proporcionaste, y resolvió al 100% el problema que tenía en mi programa